# Cursor does not move when whitespace is entered in the UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I have UITextView on screen. When I keep on entering the space in UITextView till it reaches the right boundary of UItextView then after that the cursor does not move to next line and when delete the space it feels like it is not deleting because cursor does not move. Please suggest how can I solve this problem ?

Using below code to put limit on number of charecters in UITextView

```
  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    print("count is \(textView.text.characters.count)")

    if textView == self.tv_title
    {
      if textView.text.characters.count > 49 && range.length == 0
      {
        return false
      }
      else
      {
        return true
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if textView.text.characters.count > 254 && range.length == 0
      {
        return false
      }
      else
      {
        return true
      }
}
```

Comment: Please write here the code you are using.

Comment: Why are you using range.length == 0?

Comment: I don't know.I copied this code from internet

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Please elaborate.

Comment: Please try on UitextView.When i type something in UITextView after typing 4-5 charecters when i enter space & keep on entering untill it reaches the end of UItextView right edge then cursor does not move to new line It should move to next line.But if i enter some text other than empty space then cursor move to next line

Comment: This is the delegate method of UITextView. Do you need to do anything in this method? Do you want to add any validation on text? If not, comment this method and then run your app.

Comment: When you are entering spaces move to next line with Return on keyboard.

Comment: I am handling all validations & limitations.Just need one solution which i posted